# How does terminal programs add scrolling to the screen?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, less-unix

How does the programs less, more, or vi add a scrolling section on the terminal screen without clearing the screen and how does it disappear afterwards?

Is there any way to run less for a specific amount of time if I was running it from a script or a way for the script to exit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, this has nothing to do with bash or whatever shell you're using. The `less` command itself handles its screen updates; it can be run from any shell, or from any other program.

Your terminal emulator supports *escape sequences*. Writing printable characters (letters, digits, etc.) causes those characters to be displayed. Writing escape sequences causes various other things to happen: moving the cursor, clearing the current line, clearing the screen, etc.

The `termcap` or `terminfo` and `curses` or `ncurses` software packages provide access to these escape sequences. `less`, `vim`, `emacs`, typically use `ncurses` to help manage the screen.

Two sequences relevant to your question are called `ti` and `te` by termcap, `smcup` and `rmcup` by terminfo. The `smcup` sequence causes the terminal to save its current state (everything displayed on the screen as well as the cursor position), then switches to a secondary display buffer that starts off empty. The `rmcup` sequence restores the saved state and goes back to the primary display buffer. Programs that use `ncurses` will, by default, print the `smcup` sequence on entry and the `rmcup` entry on exit. That's how such programs are able to restore your terminal window to its previous state when they terminate.

> Also is there any way to run less for a specific amount of time if i was running it from a script or a way for the script to exit

I don't think there's a really good way to do that. `less` is an interactive program; it normally terminates only when the user types `q` or something similar. Running it for a specific amount of time goes against what it's designed to do, and as a user I'd be annoyed if `less` were terminated while I'm using it.

You *could* use the `timeout` command, but that interferes with the `smcup` / `rmcup` mechanism, leaving you with a possibly corrupted display. There's probably a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: I just wanted to display a message that is updated in real time so i would want less to refresh every second or so.Doesnt matter now though because smcup and rmcup work well with i wanted to do and the tput command that i found with them is really useful. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jidder: Then you should have asked about what you're actually trying to do; see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/167210). The `watch` command is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I asked what i wanted to know. I realise how it may look like i didnt. As well as my original problem of displaying an updated message, i also(more so than the message)  wanted to know how less and similar commands worked.